# Should I run things inside a docker container as non root for safety?

Tags: docker, root

I already run my `docker build` and `docker run` without sudo. However, when I launch a process inside a docker container, it appears as a root process on `top` on the host (not inside the container).

While it cannot access the host filesystem because of namespacing and cgroups from docker, is it still more dangerous than running as a simple user?

If so, how is the right way of running things inside docker as non root?

Should I just do `USER nonroot` at the end of the Dockerfile?

**UPDATE:**

root it also needed for building some things. Should I put `USER` on the very top of the Dockerfile and then install `sudo` together with other dependencies, and then use `sudo` only when needed in the build?

Can someone give a simple Dockerfile example with USER in the beggining and installing and using `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, that's generally good practice.  Note that running `docker build` without `sudo` is distinctly _more_ dangerous than anything that might happen inside the image.

Comment: Yup, I second @DavidMaze's comment. Will note however that certain services (i.e. `sshd`) must be run as `root`, for cases such as that you can [isolate the containers with a user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) (e.g. map `root` inside of the container to a non-privileged user / non-existent UID on the host).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Running the container as `root` brings a lot of risks. Although being `root` inside the container is not the same as `root` on the host machine (some more details [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/understanding-root-inside-and-outside-container)) and you're able to deny a lot of [capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#linux-kernel-capabilities) during container startup, it is still the recommended approach to avoid being `root`.

Usually it is a good idea to use the `USER` directive in your Dockerfile after you install some general packages/libraries. In other words - after the operations that require `root` privileges. Installing `sudo` in a production service image is a mistake, unless you have a really good reason for it. In most cases - you don't need it and it is more of a security issue. If you need permissions to access some particular files or directories in the image, then make sure that the user you specified in the Dockerfile can really access them (setting proper `uid`, `gid` and other options, depending on where you deploy your container). Usually you don't need to create the user beforehand, but if you need something custom, you can always do that.

Here's an example Dockerfile for a Java application that runs under user `my-service`:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add openjdk8-jre
COPY  ./some.jar /app/
ENV SERVICE_NAME="my-service"

RUN addgroup --gid 1001 -S $SERVICE_NAME && \
    adduser -G $SERVICE_NAME --shell /bin/false --disabled-password -H --uid 1001 $SERVICE_NAME && \
    mkdir -p /var/log/$SERVICE_NAME && \
    chown $SERVICE_NAME:$SERVICE_NAME /var/log/$SERVICE_NAME

EXPOSE 8080
USER $SERVICE_NAME
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/some.jar"]
```

As you can see, I create the user beforehand and set its `gid`, disable its shell and password login, as it is going to be a 'service' user. The user also becomes owner of `/var/log/$SERVICE_NAME`, assuming it will write to some files there. Now we have a lot smaller attack surface.

Comment: what if the Dockerfile builds a library from source and then has to install the lib to a privileged folder? I don't want to build while in root, so wouldn't it make sense to install sudo and then build without sudo and use sudo to install the lib somewhere like /opt?

Comment: When you start building the image, you run all commands as `root`. You can build whatever you want under those circumstances - the result will be owned by user `root` (and most likely, depending on the `umask`, others will be able to at least read it/execute it). That should not be a problem, even if you later change the user and run everything else as that new user. You only need to be able to read the libraries, in order to load them, right? Isn't it better that they're owned by `root` then? Also, installing `sudo` won't change how you run the commands, unless you use the `USER` directive.

Comment: So shouldn't I set `USER` in the Dockerfile right in the beggining? I think you're talking about the files being generated with the root UUID, that's ok, what I think is more dangerous is processes running as root in the kernel. I was trying to avoid that. However I got more confused with yout statement that anything in the build phase is in root. Could you be more precise?

Comment: Everything runs as `root` during build time, **unless you specify another user**. If you don't, by default, the container will run as `root` as well. But, once you have the `USER` directive - every next layer will run as the new user. No problem to set your user in the beginning - just make sure you follow the least privilege principle. In other words - make sure your new user only has **enough** access to files/libraries so that your application works. Your process will never run as `root` in the kernel, because it's in a container. Just use the `USER` directive and test it out.

Comment: If you put your user at the beginning and build your application this way - this same user will own all the files that are created in the following layers. You might now always want that. It's like having write permissions on the libraries - if someone is able to break into the container and overwrite files, they'll be able to do it with the same user you're running your application with. If, however, they are owned by root - it won't be that easy. So leave root to be the owner, make sure your user can at least read the needed files and just switch to that user at the end of the Dockerfile.

Comment: What about a Dockerfile that builds a large source code as user, but install it as `sudo`? I'm concerned about the building, because running a `Makefile` as root could do anything as root.

Comment: Yes, and that's the reason why you want those files to be only owned by `root` and your running user to be different than `root`. The build phase of the image is under your control.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs there is no difference between building as `root` and using `sudo`, `make` targets will be run as a privileged user, full stop. If you're really concerned about that, consider using [multi-staged builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), Also, any changes done during the build are done in a container, not the host, so meh.

Comment: Option s is ambiguous (shell, system). Do you mean addgroup --gid 1001 -system ?

Comment: I just used this: # avoiding running the container as root reduces risk
ENV SERVICE_NAME="my-service"
RUN adduser --system --group $SERVICE_NAME
USER $SERVICE_NAME

Comment: @ChrisDanger according to https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_new_user the '-S' flag is equivalent to '--system'.

Comment: One can use a multilevel Docker image, or a separate compose service to build an image as root, and install all the libraries that need privileged access. Then this image can be used as base to build the application image intended to be run in production; in this setup one can switch to a non-root user whenever they desire and it won't interfere with installation of libraries(concern raised in first comment).

Answer (score 10):

## Why you shouldn't run as root

While other people have pointed out that you shouldn't run images as root, there isn't much information here, or in the docs about why that is.

While it's true that there is a difference between having root access to a container and root access on the host, root access on a container is still very powerful.

Here is a really good article that goes in depth on the difference between the two, and this issue in general:

https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/understanding-root-inside-and-outside-container

The general point is that if there is a malicious process in your container, it can do whatever it wants in the container, from installing packages, uploading data, hijacking resources, you name it, it can do it.

This also makes it easier for a process to break out of the container and gain privileges on the host since there are no safeguards within the container itself.

## How and when to run as non-root

What you want to do is run all your installation and file download/copy steps as root (a lot of things need to be installed as root, and in general it's just a better practice for the reasons I outline below). Then, explicitly create a user and grant that user the minimum level of access that they need to run the application. This is done through the use of `chmod` and `chown` commands.

Immediately before your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` directive, you then add a `USER` directive to switch to the newly created user. This will ensure that your application runs as a non-root user, and that user will only have access to what you explicitly gave it access to in previous steps.

The general idea is that the user that runs the container should have an absolute minimum of permissions (most of the time the user doesn't need read, write, and execute access to a file). That way, if there is a malicious process in your container, its behavior will be as restricted as possible. This means that you should avoid creating or copying in any files, or installing any packages as that user too, since they would have complete control over any resources they create by default. I've seen comments suggesting otherwise. Ignore them. If you want to be in line with security best practices, you would then have to go back and revoke the user's excess permissions, and that would just be awful and error prone.

Comment: "This also makes it easier for a process to break out of the container and gain privileges on the host since there are no safeguards within the container itself.."- can you demonstrate that with examples?

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the CIS benchmark for Docker and they recommend to use non-root and this is one of the "Compliance" checks.  Adding USER non-root at the bottom should suffice or you can use '-u' with your RUN command to specify user as well.

https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/docker/
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: should I put `USER` on beggining of the Dockerfile or in the end? Should I install sudo and use it when needed only?

Comment: At the end should be fine

Answer (score -1):

Running your containers as non-root gives you an extra layer of security. By default, Docker containers are run as root, but this allows for unrestricted container activities.

Comment: What kind of security we talk about? containers are already isolated from the host!!

Comment: @RamPrakash a quick look around the web might surprise you, e.g. https://blog.aquasec.com/container-isolation - "A container isn’t a strong security boundary. They provide some restrictions on access to shared resources on a host, but they don’t necessarily prevent a malicious attacker from circumventing these restrictions."