# Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions in Dockerfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-venv

RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

Everything works file until this line:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Using `docker run --rm -it name bash` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` then I found this error:

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting 
behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment
instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673221/warning-running-pip-as-the-root-user), I found solution (which didn't work for me), that it's possible to resolve just by creating new user, but it doesn't seem to be optimal solution. How can I fix this?

Comment: _but it doesn't seem to be optimal solution_ > on what are you basing this statement?

Comment: I mean, it seems to be a little bit weird - create user, just to give him permissions to  execute script, but still, didn't work for me.

Comment: Well, that's the way though. The warning of pip point you at that _you should ideally not run pip as root_. If you are not willing to comply with the warning, nothing forces you, though, so, just ignore it, or use a virtual environment, as pointed by the warning.

Comment: And if the said answer did not work for you, then please be more precise **what** did not work for you?

Comment: Also worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68155641/should-i-run-things-inside-a-docker-container-as-non-root-for-safety

Comment: In that solution this line - `ENV PATH="/home/myuser/.local/bin:$PATH"` - didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was in version of images. Using this `Dockerfile` I was able to fix this:

```
FROM python:3.9.3

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

PS. I don't really know if it was about it, but this images has the same python version, that I have on my computer. I could have impact on dependencies.

Comment: you probably still run pip as root user. the thing is in a docker container, it doesnt matter too much, because you install only this one set of depenecies and dont have multiple packages and so on. I think its still better practice to use a venv.