# How to deploy a docker container from within another container on the host machine?

Tags: docker, go, microservices

I'm working on a cloud-native application that follows microservice architecture, there is a feature in the applcation that when it requires, it deploys adapters (they're part of the application) withing docker containers from UI of the application, while the application's server itself is running withing a docker container. `/var/run/docker.sock` is mounted to the application's container and docker go client library is used to deploy these containers.

## What is error?

When deploying container getting permission denied error.

```
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock
```

## How the application is deployed on docker?

the application has a CLI module written in golang, which deploys application on docker by executing `docker-compose.yaml up` command programmatically.

## What solutions did I try?

first I attempted running the user as `root` in `Dockerfile`, However, due to security implications, this approach is not advisable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263675/22766698).
Next, I tried adding the `group_add` option to the `docker-compose.yaml` file programmatically using the following code:

```
_, host, _ := strings.Cut(client.DefaultDockerHost, "://")
        var stat syscall.Stat_t
        err = syscall.Stat(host, &stat)
        if err != nil {
            utils.Log.Info("Error while accessing docker socket `", host, "` file\n", err.Error(),
                "\nDue to this error, you won't be able to provision adapters from either Meshery UI and mesheryctl\n")
        } else {
            groupAdd := utils.ViperCompose.GetStringSlice("services.meshery.group_add")
            groupAdd = append(groupAdd, fmt.Sprintf("%d", stat.Gid))
            utils.ViperCompose.Set("services.meshery.group_add", groupAdd)

            // Write the modified configuration back to the Docker Compose file
            if err := utils.ViperCompose.WriteConfig(); err != nil {
                utils.Log.Info("Error while writing configuration file\n", err.Error(),
                    "Due to this error, you won't be able to provision adapters from either Meshery UI and mesheryctl")
            }
        }
```

I have docker-compose file loaded into [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) instance which allows editing configuration files programmatically. in the code snippet I retrieved default docker host's path and extracted its gid and supplied it in `group_add` option's value in `docker-compose.yaml` file. this solution worked as well, but doesn't seem consistent and safe to senior or me as well.

I would appreciate your suggestions regarding my above `group_add` solution or if there is any official solution from Docker or the community to achieve the expected results.

Comment: Have you tried to run the container in privilege mode?

Comment: If you're going to say "due to security implications..." then you can't have access to the host's Docker socket – it's almost trivial to use it to compromise the entire host system.  The mechanics of launching new containers will also be very dependent on your container system, plain Docker vs. Kubernetes vs. ECS vs. Nomad will all work differently.  Can you restructure your application to avoid dynamically launching containers at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for replying, the adapters in the application are optional if the user requires them, the user deploys them. so we're constrained to use this method. the adapters are gRPC services, do you know about any strategy to enable users to dynamically provision adapters?

Comment: @HernanGarcia did privileged work? No.